# Ubuntu 16.04LTS and Win 10 problem

Tags: dual-boot, startup, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS to my original Win 10 . When i select Windows it doesnt start properly . sometimes it make some orange(violet i dont know exact colour) screen with grains in it and somrtimes it says "diagnosing the PC" or going to "automatic Repair". What i have to do? .Is it possible to have dual OS in Win 10 or not? If it so please suggest me steps to do proper installation of both OS.

Comment: Check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) Ubuntu official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu running on my machine. I can recommend few troubleshooting tips:

- Check if your pc is in bios mode or UEFI mode. When installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode and other operating system is installed as BIOS mode, booting to other OS may cause some problems.
- I have secure boot disabled in BIOS as it prevents me to have dual OS. check your setting.
- try running update grub command in linux to check if os prober finds a proper windows OS. this command should do the task.

  sudo update-grub

Comment: The answer is very useful but I'm getting the error still now 1. I checked secure boot its disabled, updated grub, even in installing I didn't use UEFI mode in ubuntu I  clicked "Go back" option in that. @shahs will u able to add more troubleshooting tips for me!?

Comment: I am afraid I do not remember further troubleshooting tips, if you have orignal DVD of your windows, you can start a new install of windows and then instead of installing a new windows, choose repair option, may that could help you but i am not sure.